# Too many brk() noticed in strace

Tags: c++, performance, malloc, mmap, brk

I have a c++ service, where I am trying to debug the cause of high service startup time. From strace logs I notice a lot of brk() (which contributes to about 300ms, which is very high for our SLA). On studying further , I see brk() to be a memory management call which helps control amount of memory allocated to data segment of the process.  malloc() can use brk() (for small allocations) or mmap (for big allocations) based on situation.

Logs from strace:

`891905 1674977609.119549 mmap2(NULL, 163840, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf6a01000 <0.000051>`

`891905 1674977609.119963 brk(0x209be000) = 0x209be000 <0.000025>`

`891905 1674977609.120495 brk(0x209df000) = 0x209df000 <0.000022>`

`891905 1674977609.121167 brk(0x20a00000) = 0x20a00000 <0.000041>`

`891905 1674977609.121776 brk(0x20a21000) = 0x20a21000 <0.000024>`

`891905 1674977609.122327 brk(0x20a42000) = 0x20a42000 <0.000024>`

`...`

`..`

`.`

`891905 1674977609.427039 brk(0x2432b000) = 0x2432b000 <0.000064>`

`891905 1674977609.427827 brk(0x2434c000) = 0x2434c000 <0.000069>`

`891905 1674977609.428695 brk(0x2436d000) = 0x2436d000 <0.000050>   0     0     2     2`

I believe , there is way number of brk() calls called, which has a scope for improving efficiency . I am trying play around with tunables such as M_TRIM_THRESHOLD, M_MMAP_THRESHOLD to reduce the number of brk() , but I don't notice any change.

https://www.linuxjournal.com/files/linuxjournal.com/linuxjournal/articles/063/6390/6390s2.html

For instance , this is one of the ways I tried to make the changes before restarting the service. The service is running as a docker container, so I am trying to make the changes on the docker container and on the host. , but I don't notice any change.

export MALLOC_MMAP_THRESHOLD_=131072

export MALLOC_TRIM_THRESHOLD_=131072

export MALLOC_MMAP_MAX_=65536

Am I trying to hit the wrong target , or is my understanding there is lot of fragmentation that is happening is wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `brk` = "give me more heap". This is a fast way for libc (malloc/new) to ask for more memory from the kernel, if you manage to convert it to `mmap`, you will make things **slower**. This is a symptom of the program doing loads of allocations at startup. You are unlikely to improve things by focusing on this symptom.

Comment: If you have the source code to the service, you can try to take a memory debugger (valgrind/massif) to it and understand what the allocations are for. If not, there may not be much you can do.

Comment: Or a general profiler, the program may be spending the time in some other way, not necessarily related to memory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @teapot418. Yes , I read that mmap would be slower than brk , and thats why smaller allocations are chosen for brk. But just for academic interest , I was trying to see how much worse the lag gets with mmap . i.e with multiple brk() , i know i would see 300ms . With couple of mmap , how much worse would the lag get is what I am trying to understand.By theory, if i set M_MMAP_THRESHOLD to 0. shouldn't malloc choose mmap always and never call brk(). Is my understanding wrong.

Comment: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26663 <- some discussion about setting the threshold to zero, but yes, that should force it to use mmap for all allocations, see also https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html#2568